# IO Exception when i use "FileUtils.copyURLToFile(urlConnection.getURL(), exportFile);"

Tags: java

**Summary:**
I am trying to save the pdf file which will be generated from the API using `FileUtils.copyURLToFile(urlConnection.getURL(), exportFile);` but getting `401 error`.

**Error:**

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://8901-7M0W2X2.KMX.LOCAL/api/comparison/cekdotljl8r98d827gw1y7xvh/result/pdf
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1460)
    at sampleAPI.Main.main(Main.java:63)
```

I have authenticated the connection but getting the same error.

**Written Code:**

```java
try {
    String name = "****";
    String password = "****";
    File exportFile = new File(
            "C:/New folder/result.pdf");
    String webPage = "http://8901-7M0W2X2.KMX.LOCAL:80/api/comparison/compare?file1=file:X/Letter_0.pdf&file1=file:X/Letter_2.pdf&result=pdf&visible=true&profile=MyStyle";
    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
    URL url = new URL(webPage);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(urlConnection.getURL(), exportFile);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please provide your suggestion to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the 401 indicates your authentication is missing or wrong. Check your credentials and base64 encoding are correct. Additionally keep in mind that the server might return the wrong status (your's seems to be some local webserver): 401 is called "unauthorized" but actually means "unauthenticated". Because of the confusing names I have seen several cases of servers returning 401 for authenticated but unauthorized requests.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this by using InputStream and FileOutPutStream

```
response = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        while ((i = response.read()) != -1) {
            fileOut.write(i);
        }
        fileOut.close();
```

Thanks!